# Downloading all subscriber lists and viewing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ftp

I recently tried to download the full 'All Subscribers' list and it says that the file is to big and placed it into an FTP file within Salesforce/ExactTarget Marketing Cloud.  I am trying to locate where this file would be.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to contact [SFMC Support](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/contact_us/) if you don't have the sFTP URL and credentials.  It'll be in the Export directory.  The [help site](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/file_transfer_location/) has some additional information about SFMC File Locations.